# Kusto\KQL - Render timechart for simple count value

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-log-analytics, kql, azure-monitoring

I have a kql-query which calculates number of uploaded BLOBS in Azure storage since last 24 hours.
The query blow returns a number as expected when run in Azure log analytics.

```
StorageBlobLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) and OperationName has "PutBlob" and StatusText contains "success" a
| distinct Uri
| summarize count()
```

I want now to visualise this information in a timechart to get some detailed view. Have tried to add "render timechart" to the query chain as follows

```
StorageBlobLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) and OperationName has "PutBlob" and StatusText contains "success" a
| distinct Uri
| summarize count()
| render timechart
```

When executing the query however, i am getting the error message;

> Failed to create visualization
> The Stacked bar chart can't be created as you are missing a column of one of the following types: int, long, decimal or real

Any tips to how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you wish to look at the data aggregated at an hourly resolution (for example) and rendered as a timechart, you could try this:

```
StorageBlobLogs
| where TimeGenerated > ago(1d) and OperationName has "PutBlob" and StatusText contains "success"
| summarize dcount(Uri) by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
| render timechart
```